# How to select from drop-down list through Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to select a value from a drop-down list that indicates the number of posts that are displayed from the website.

```
<form method="get" class="forumForm">
        <label for="dispItems">Show items:</label> 
        <select id="dispItems" class="dispItems">
            <option selected="selected">15</option>
            <option>30</option>
            <option>60</option>
            <option>90</option>
            <option>120</option>
            <option>150</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

I want to change this so that the last option is selected. Through other answers I've tried to the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dispItems"))

# None of these two options work.
select.select_by_index(4)            # Option 1.
select.select_by_visible_text("150") # Option 2.
```

Both option 1 and option 2 return the following error message:

```
WebDriverException: Message:
```

If I try:

```
select.select_by_visible_text("random")
```

I get the following error message:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: random
```

Edit: The solution, as proposed by KunduK is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH    ,'//select[@id="dispItems"][@class="dispItems"]')))
time.sleep(1)
select=Select(element)
time.sleep(1)
select.select_by_visible_text('150')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `WebDriverWait` this should work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//select[@id="dispItems"][@class="dispItems"]')))
select=Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text('150')
```

OR

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//select[@id="dispItems"][@class="dispItems"]')))
element.click()
element.send_keys(Keys.END)
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

**EDITED:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//select[@id="dispItems"][@class="dispItems"]')))
element.click()
time.sleep(2)
element.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(2)
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: The first suggestion just returns the "empty" error message. The second one actually clicks the second option! (I want the last option)

Comment: Here in my laptop it is selecting 150 for both.However do one thing on second option just give time.sleep(2) before sendkeys.

Comment: @ThomasWear : Just check edited answer and let me know how it goes?

Comment: It didn't work. But I tried switching browser to Firefox and using the time.sleep with  Ratmir's solution and it worked. Thank you for taking your time to help me! :)

Edit: It was actually your first suggestion that worked with the time.pause(2)!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the explicit wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


select = Select(ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "dispItems"))))
select.select_by_index(4)
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below to select last item 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(“(//select[‘dispItems’]/option)[last()]”).click()

Comment: Try to add Expected Condition and wait until element present